# How to configure google's identity platform as a REST api that can be hit using postman

Tags: rest, microsoft-identity-platform

how to comfigure google's identity platform as a REST api that can be hit using postman. configuring google cloud identity platform and also i need to perform user operation via postman, also i need to implement multi-tenant with identity platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.